# Apple asking for iPad screenshot (in iTunes Connect) on iPhone app?

Tags: ios, itunes, app-store-connect

Quick and hopefully obvious question.  I'm setting up my app to be submitted, and I'm working in iTunes Connect.  It's asking me for iPhone and iPad screenshots.  Is it okay to leave out the iPad screenshots if your build is only for iPhone (as in I have set the device in target to iPhone)?  It seems redundant to take a screenshot of my app running in 2x move on an iPad.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Is it okay to leave out the iPad screenshots if your build is only for iPhone (as in I have set the device in target to iPhone)?

Yes.

Comment: @chriseen You only have to provide iPad screenshots for universal or iPad apps. I just pushed an app to Apple review and only provided iPhone screenshots. I know for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If your app is iPhone-only (in terms of layout), don't give them doubled iPad shots.