# Itunes connect screenshots require ipad even though project only for iphone

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

In xcode project devices is set to iphone but in itunes connect when i try to upload my app to the app store in itunes connect, the screenshots require me to post screenshots for ipad and ipad pro,

Comment: Have you tried submitting it? The iTunes Connect page always shows spaces for iPad screenshots, but in my experience you can just leave them blank and submit with just the iPhone screenshots.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8342098/1806873

Answer (score 37):

In your project setting, in General tab, under Deployment info, set Devices from Universal to iPhone [image]

Answer (score 16):

I know it's a bit late but I am just posting this here in case somebody else needs it.
After universal apps, it seems that an XCode version shipped with a bug where the `project.pbxproj` thinks its a universal app (`TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = "1,2";`) even though the `iPad` checkbox is unticked in the project info.

To solve this, you can either:
 - check and uncheck the `iPad` checkbox (I know...). You should see the difference with `git status`
 - manually change to `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = "1"`;

Comment: Keep in mind once you've uploaded an app with support for both iPhone and iPad and gotten it published, you can NOT remove the device support later, Apple will reject any submissions that remove a platform (possibly only applies to iPhone or iPad and not tvOS/watchOS).

Comment: Can the support be later added though?